# Magento 2. How to fix errors with retrieving category and product attributes

Tags: php, function, magento2

I have adjusted the following code to execute two different functions that would get and retrieve some category and product attributes for a Magento 2 template. However, the code does not execute correctly and I only get a white screen to see. Any ideas where this goes wrong? I do not get any syntax errors to see.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

$objectManager      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product            = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

$offertelink        = $product->getData('offerte_link');
$image              = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$product->getData('grootmateriaal_extra_image_int');

$_categoryHelper    = $this->helper('Custom\Config\Helper\Category');
$_productHelper     = $this->helper('Custom\Config\Helper\Product');

$attributes = array_slice(explode(',', $_categoryHelper->getCurrentCategoryData('category_attributes')),0, 6);
$getIconsValues = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('icons')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

function getCategoryAttributes($_categoryHelper) {

    if($_categoryHelper->getCurrentCategoryData('category_attributes')):
        foreach($attributes as $attr):
        $attr = $_productHelper->getAttributeByCode(trim($attr));

        echo '<div class="pd-icon pd-icon-'.$attr.'">';
            echo $_productHelper->getAttributeText($product, $attr);
        echo '</div>';

    endforeach; endif;

    echo '<div class="pd-icon-button-container">';
        echo '<a class="button large cta" href="<?php echo $offertelink; ?>"><span>';
        echo __('Ask');
        echo '</span></a>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="pd-icon-button-container">';
        echo '<a class="button open" href="#amasty-downloads"><span>';
        echo __('Download');
        echo '</span></a>';
    echo '</div>';

    if ($image):
        echo '<div class="pd-icon-image-container">';
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="">';
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
}

function getProductAttributes($_categoryHelper) {
$iconen_array = explode(',', $getIconsValues);
    foreach($iconen_array as $a):
        echo '<div class="pd-icon pd-icon-'.strtolower(trim($a)).'">';
        $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute(strtolower(trim($a)));
        echo $attr->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
}

?>

<div class="pd-icon-container">

    <?php if($product->hasData('icons')): ?>

    <?php if ( empty ($getIconsValues) ):
        getCategoryAttributes($objectManager); ?>

    <?php else:
        getProductAttributes($objectManager); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php else:
        getCategoryAttributes($objectManager); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check your code as of now.I can give you some suggestions like better to avoid using Object manager directly using to fetch data. Here I can show you the example for getting category list and you can change your way and also you can add the attribute function to get in same.

referral link for avoiding direct use of Object manager:
[https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html][1]

The code for getting category using dependency injection You can use the below as example :

> Hope you familiar with creating New Modules

Sample File Path: app/code/YourVendorName/YourModuleName/Block/YourCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false) {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // set pagination
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize); 
        } 

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true) {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true);
    }
}
```

Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows

```
// get the list of all categories
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}

// get categories sorted by category name
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(true, false, 'name', false);
foreach ($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}

// get current store’s categories
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

If the answer is helpful to you please don't forget to tick.